# Gitlab hook on opening merge request

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, gitlab, buildbot

I have a buildbot server and Gitlab. I could not figure out, to trigger builds whenever a merge request is opened on Gitlab. The purpose should be, that buildbot writes a comment back to the merge request whenever a build succeeds or fails (where as the build is done on the merge request + the upstream branch).

Any hints how to trigger that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gitlab team actually merged some stuff in to make it possible to fire web hooks whenever a merge request is opened or updated:
 see https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/5881 and 
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1137

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a `service` like the one for [`GitLab CI`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/eb421c88ee2a57a437b9b14ba7447a04720354ac/app/models/project_services/drone_ci_service.rb). This actually posts back to the merge-request whether `GitLab CI` passed or failed the test-suite.

Comment: ho would you plug such a service in? I can't really see any code that reacts to actions... Sorry, my Ruby knowledge is very limited.

Comment: I'm also not a ruby dev. I guess this service delegates its action to another hook. Maybe look at the implementation for the hip chat service which maybe is more intuitive: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/483f9854e43d2a3fc6cf48ec7228ddef62b93375

Comment: thanks for that link, that explains more how the stuff works. When I get it right, the execute_service thingy is only called whenever you push something. But the creation for a merge request is not a push action. I am thinking about extending the merge_controller (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/app/controllers/projects/merge_requests_controller.rb) for doing something whenever a merge request is created.

Comment: Link is now a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented one and am contributing it back to the buildbot project, see https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/1820

It uses webhooks and posts comments back to the merge request to show build status.